# How to change Eclipse's input box area's color from "Find/Replace" or "Search"

Tags: eclipse, customization

I have a problem using Eclipse with DevStyle's Darkest Dark theme.

Eclipse version : Oxygen 3a
OS : Mac Mohave, (Dark mode currently using)

I tried to uninstall the theme and reinstall it, but the same thing happened. I also tried to find a place where I can change its color, but I could not figure it out.

Text is written in the input area, but it's impossible to read as its background color and text color are almost identical.

[image: text is written in input area, but it's not readable as its background color and text color are almost identical]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to come to this issue late - this was a **known issue** with the previous version of DevStyle on Oxygen + Mojave. If you update the DevStyle installation, or a do a fresh install, you should no longer have this problem as we specifically added Mojave support (esp. the new dark mode) for Oxygen too.

For more on this particular release, read this [blog post](https://www.genuitec.com/devstyle-adds-mojave-dark-more/).